# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Tags: python

Working on scripts to connect to AWS and recently started getting this error when I try to install a python module or execute a script I get the following error:

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

It appears I have defined the certificate in the environment path so not sure what else to use to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: are you using macOS?

Comment: No Windows 10.  Believe the issue I'm having is related to security changes in the work environment.

Answer (score 6):

This can happen when Python is unable to verify the authenticity of the SSL certificate presented by the server.

Temporarily, try to disable certificate verification using the **verify=False** option in the requests library. However, this should not be used in production code:

```
import requests
url = "https://example.com"
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

If it works, then try to check your environment:

- Try updating the *certifi* package which contains the trusted certificates bundle. You can do this using **pip**. `pip install --upgrade certifi`
- Make sure that the system clock on your machine is correctly set. SSL/TLS connections rely on accurate timekeeping.
- If you're behind a proxy, make sure your proxy settings are configured correctly.
- Ensure that you haven't set any environment variables that override the system's certificate store. In some cases, setting *SSL_CERT_FILE* or *REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE* could cause certificate verification issues.
- If none of the above steps work, you can try explicitly specifying the path to the certificate file in your Python code using the verify parameter of the *requests* library. For example:

  ```
   import requests
   url = "https://example.com"
   response = requests.get(url, verify="/path/to/certificate.crt")
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Typically this means that you were unable to verify the authenticity of the certificate presented by the server when checking it against your CA certificate bundle.

The particular message: `unable to get local issuer certificate` indicates that the path to the CA bundle is either missing, or that the CA cert is not in your bundle.

Comment: and from the OPs comment "related to security changes in the work environment", it's almost certainly a CA cert for a VPN like zscaler or cloudflare that has to be added to the bundle

Answer (score 2):

Try *pip install pip-system-certs* in the command line.

I've been struggeling with the CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error as well when using the *request* module. I tried installing *certifi* but that didn't help. The only solution to my problem was to install *pip-system-certs*. For some reason that allowed request to access a local certificate.

Also: *requests.get(url, verify=False)* is not recommended for production environment because you basically turn safety off.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by installing the package `pip-system-certs` using the `--use-feature=truststore` option:

```
python -m pip install pip-system-certs --use-feature=truststore
```

or upgrade the package

```
python -m pip install pip-system-certs -U --use-feature=truststore
```

It might be necessary to restart the terminal or application you are using before the effects are noticable.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set **SSL_CERT_DIR** environment variable:

```
SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs/
```

Comment: they using windows not mac or linux